# how to show the path along with the time spent on each field from the sqlite database?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables which are related to each other in the form of id's. I want to get the path along with the time spent.The date is in PR time format.

**Places**

Id       ***_*__**        Course   **__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**   last_ visit_date

---

1      ----------------    English  -------------------  1364407154328000

2  ----------------------- Maths -----------------------  1364321118380000

3  ---------------------- Economics  -----------------     1364320870167000

**Visits**

from   ***_*__*_*__*_*____** place_id  ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_***   visit_date

1 ----------------------------- 2  ------------------------   1364320856866000

2  -----------------------------  3  ------------------------  1364320857080000

***Output****

from  ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_***  To  ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**  duration

English  ------------------   Maths  ------------------------  2:00:00

Maths  ----------------------- Economics --------------------  2:00:20

i can show the path but am unable to show the duration along with the path.how to join this two tables together.

I appreciate your help!!

Comment: Please show us your query

Comment: I don't see how you arrive at 2:00:00 and 2:00:00? Is it the `visit_date - last_ visit_date`?

Comment: Ya it's last_visit_date- visit_date

Comment: SELECT time( (p.last_visit_date - h.visit_date) / 1000000, 'unixepoch')
FROM places p JOIN visits h ON p.id = h.id;

Comment: I can show the path as well as time but i want all of them in one table..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the same values as you present, but the idea is this:

```
SELECT p1.Course, p2.Course, time((p2.last_visit_date-v.visit_date)/1000000,'unixepoch')
    FROM Visits v
    INNER JOIN Places p1 ON v.from_id=p1.id
    INNER JOIN Places p2 ON v.place_id=p2.id;
```

The idea is to join twice with Places, one for the first Course, the other for the last Course.

(Note that I changed your "from" field to "from_id". You can still use from if you specify it between backticks, but I think it's best to avoid name collisions like this.)